# Voting If/Else/Elif

Tags: python, if-statement

New to Python (and to StackOverflow). Trying to figure out how to get this to execute properly. While the program itself executes fine, I'd like it to not have the extra step in there. What I mean by that is that if it fails the first statement, I'd like to to terminate and print the message associated with the else statement.

```
def main():

    # init
    messageOne = 'You are too young to vote.'
    messageTwo = 'You can vote.'
    messageThree = 'You need to register before you can vote.'

    # input
    age = int(input('Please enter your age: '))
    registration = input('Are you registered to vote(Y/N)?: ')

    # calculate / display
    if age >= 18:
        if registration.upper() == "Y":
            print(messageTwo)
        else:
            print(messageThree)
    else:
        print(messageOne)

main()
```

Comment: Can we assume the lack of indentation in the body of the `main` function is a copy-paste error rather than the actual code? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52562991/edit) to correct it.
It's also not clear what you're wanting the behaviour to be - would you edit your question to provide an *example input and output that clarifies*?

Comment: Sorry. Is that better? Just so I know for future reference.

Comment: Yep, the formatting is much better: but your question could still benefit massively from an example of an input and output that demonstrate the change in behaviour that you're after. Code/examples of input/output are always easier to understand than a wordy description.

Comment: Gotcha. Still learning. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is written well. The only think I would change is put `registration = input('Are you registered to vote(Y/N)?: ')` after checking if `age >= 18` (so the user won't be asked if they are registered if they are younger than 18). I wouldn't change anything else.

```
def main():

    # init
    messageOne = 'You are too young to vote.'
    messageTwo = 'You can vote.'
    messageThree = 'You need to register before you can vote.'

    # input
    age = int(input('Please enter your age: '))

    # calculate / display
    if age >= 18:
        registration = input('Are you registered to vote(Y/N)?: ')
        if registration.upper() == "Y":
            print(messageTwo)
        else:
            print(messageThree)
    else:
        print(messageOne)

main()
```

Comment: Thanks. That definitely works out. I didn't think to move the registration input into the calculation.

Comment: No problem! Put a checkmark next to this answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside a function, you can skip remaining statements with `return`.

```
def main():

    # init
    messageOne = 'You are too young to vote.'
    messageTwo = 'You can vote.'
    messageThree = 'You need to register before you can vote.'

    # input
    age = int(input('Please enter your age: '))


    # calculate / display
    if age < 18:
         print(messageOne)
         return    
    registration = input('Are you registered to vote(Y/N)?: ')
    if registration.upper() == "Y":
         print(messageTwo)
         return
    print(messageThree)
    return

main()
```

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't seem like the books I'm looking at have talked about return yet, but I appreciate the input.